# What is the difference between search domains and nameservers?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, nameserver, resolv.conf

I've usually seen two kinds of entries in `/etc/resolv.conf` on certain servers. The `domain-name-servers` entry specifies which DNS to use for resolving hostnames to IP addresses. Recently I saw an entry for `search IP_ADDRESS`. So here's my question. What's the difference between a nameserver and a search domain?

Comment: The value specified with `search` must be a domain rather than an IP address. It is plausible that if the DHCP server is misconfigured and neither server nor client validate the value, that you could end up with an IP address being written into `resolv.conf`. It may also be that the invalid value in `resolv.conf` was placed there manually.

Answer (score 15):

the `search` indicate what domain(s) to append to your host name in a search. for example if you run this command :

```
ping myserver
```

if you do not have anything in the search domain, it will search for "myserver" in your hostfile, and if nothing there, it will return

```
unknown host
```

but if you add `search mydomain.com`

then the same ping would return

```
64 bytes from myserver.mydomain.com (some ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=415 ms
```

(provided the "myserver.mydomain.com actually exist, and reply to ping requests)

`nameserver` on the other hand is the IP address of your actual DNS server, where you look up all hostnames that is not in your hosts file.

edit: added some more details, and the 2nd part of the question (nameserver)

Comment: sorry, I accidentally deleted someones edit of my post.. while I was editing it myself.. I have added the change that was made myself. thanks for help.

Comment: No problems - thanks for taking it so well.  +1 from me, by the way - good answer.

Answer (score 3):

- A name server entry tells the system what name servers to ask for name resolution.
- A search domain provides a default domain name for searches. If you provide `example.net` and `example.com` as search domains and try to contact the host `server1`, the system will look for `server1.example.net` and `server1.example.com` without you having to type out the full domain.